# replace foreach for LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, foreach

How can I do this using LINQ?

```
var prop = new List<EventProposal>();
foreach (var eventProposal in @event.Proposals)
      foreach (var service in eventProposal.Services)
      {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(service.LongDescription))
            {
                  prop.Add(eventProposal);
                  break;
            }
      }
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension method syntax:

```
prop = @event.Proposals.Where(p => p.Services.Any(
           s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.LongDescription)).ToList();
```

Or query:

```
prop = (from p in @event.Proposals
        where p.Services.Any(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.LongDescription))
        select p).ToList();
```

**NOTE**

The logic in your example may not be what you intended; as it stands, it will only add the item if the *first* `Service` has a non-empty `LongDescription` (because the `break` is outside the `if`, so it will break on the first item regardless of whether or not it fits the condition). The logic above is assuming that the example is wrong and you want to add it if *any* of them have a non-empty `LongDescription`.

If, however, that is what you want, then try this:

```
prop = @event.Proposals.Where(
       p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(
       p.Services.Select(s => s.LongDescription).FirstOrDefault())).ToList();
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a list of Proposals, not Services, as your methods return.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You right, I wrote the sample in the moment and forget about the {} :P.

I can not vote because I new, but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines. Don't have the ability to compile and check this, and I don't know if it is honestly clearer than the nested foreach.

```
var prop = @event.Proposals.Aggregate(
           new List<EventProposal>(), 
           (list, proposal) => { list.AddRange(proposal.Services
                                               .Where(service =>
                                                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(service.LongDescription)));                                      
                                 return list;
                                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prop = @event.Proposals
   .Where(proposal => proposal.Services.All(service => 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(service.LongDescription))))
   .ToList();
```

This returns all the proposals in `@event` where all of the proposal's services have non-null `LongDescription` values. The `ToList()` is optional, only if you want the result as `IList<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from proposal in @event.Proposals
where proposal.Services.Any(service => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(service.LongDescription))
select proposal;
```